# PuTTY or other Windows SSH client: mouse wheel to scroll less/more or other pager on UNIX server?

Tags: ssh, terminal, scrolling

I like GNOME terminal because when you ssh to a server and run commands such as `man init` then you can use the scroll wheel to navigate the man page.

Unfortunately my Windows SSH clients do not support this.

How can I find an SSH client that supports this short of operating a Linux VM?

Edit: I found that PuTTY supports this in vim when you use `:set mouse=a`.

However, with commands like `less`, I can only seem to get it to work in GNOME terminal. Surely there's a way to make this work with PuTTY also? I'm also open to suggestions of alternate Windows SSH clients.

Comment: Simple: use Linux :-)

Comment: That would be so cool! Unfortunately I cannot wash my hands of Windows just yet. (although I could try to get Windows in a VM, just don't feel like doing all that just yet)

Comment: An alternative windows client would indeed be one way to get this. Another would be to just use a remote desktop client and remote into a real Gnome desktop from windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding `less`, it is done all in the terminal emulator, because `less` is unaware of the mouse.

The way it works with gnome-terminal is that it sees that the program switches to the [alternate screen](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (an xterm feature) and since normal wheel mouse scrolling would be pointless (the alternate screen does *not* scroll), the developer chose to send up/down cursor-key escape sequences.  That works with `less`, just as if you pressed those keys on the keyboard.

PuTTY does not have this feature; its development has been glacial for several years.  A comparable feature was added to `xterm` in [2012](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282), called `alternateScroll`.

Before (or if the feature is not used), [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/) (which Putty imitates) would send a different escape sequence for the wheel mouse, but only if the program sends an escape sequence to turn on the mouse protocol.  `less` does not do this (and actually does not expect to read `xterm` mouse escape-sequences).

Because the feature in gnome-terminal relies upon the terminal description using the alternate screen, that means that *it* will work on say half of the various systems, since people liking or disliking the feature seem to be fairly evenly split.

Comment: Your info on the alternate screen has been quite helpful.